# Creating a line of code and a script to call back database information in a table from another site (like with twitter, analytics etc)

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, twitter

I am interested in how things like google analytics, and the twitter widget work.

For instance in twitter:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/user" data-widget-id="user-id-in-numbers">Tweets by @user</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){
        var js,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';

        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }

    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

So essentially this line of text is put on one page of a site unrelated to twitter.

Then it calls some funky long javascript which is minified and difficult to understand (as it's all letters and convolution even when un-minified) and somehow this contacts the api, gets the information, creates a table pre-designed with css and puts it on the original website.

In short I wanted to build an API, much like it, where I pass information from my database through to a website with a nice pretty layout and such.

The question is - what is this called? It's not a RESTful API surely? Those look different and are sort of URL driven, unless it is calling a restful url within the javascript or something.

Basically I'd love to learn and work it out, but I can't think of what to query on google to learn from, to find a tutorial, because I don't know what this is called. Except that a lot of the 'big guys' in tech use it with amazing results.

Thanks

Comment: It is just a javascript API.  Why it works is because your page actually loads script *from* their site onto *your* site, which allows them to pass data about your site to their site, and to run a script (that they control) on your site that can load content, etc.  It also gives them control over the look / feel of the content that gets loaded.

Comment: "Script injection", one would assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a proper name for these things, but similar things are called widgets. As for how these things work, basically, it creates a new script tag with the `src` set to the URL of a JavaScript file that runs on the page the code was added to, usually creating a new set of elements or an iframe. The script is able to do this because externally loaded JavaScript files run in the security context of the site then linked to them, so the user must trust the host of the script not to serve malicious code. Here is an explanation of how Twitter's code works.

Basically, it creates the following script tag and adds it to the DOM, right before the first script tag on the page (if using HTTPS, the src will be `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`).

```
<script id="twitter-wjs" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Here is a commented breakdown of the code.

```
//Everything is wrapped in self-calling an anonymous function to prevent variable collision.
!function(d,s,id){
    var js,
    //Find the first script element in the DOM (s = "script")
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    //Create a URL prefix, using http if document.location starts with "http" (d = document)
    p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';

    //If the script tag with the ID of "twitter-wjs" has not been added yet (id = "twitter-wjs")
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        //Create a new script tag (s = "script")
        js=d.createElement(s);
        //Set the id to "twitter-wjs"
        js.id=id;
        //Set the src to the URL to the external script using the prefix from above.
        js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        //Insert the new script tag before the first script in the DOM causing it to load the external JS file.
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");//Call the function, with these arguments.
```

It should be noted that all of this code could simple be written as the following.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/user" data-widget-id="user-id-in-numbers">Tweets by @user</a>
<script id="twitter-wjs" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

If you plan on making your own, I recommend using this method for protocol independent script tags. It's cleaner, faster, smaller, and perfectly well supported.